# Java regexp Pattern find empty HTML/XML elements

Tags: java, html, regex

I've got a problem finding empty HTML elements in a multiline HTML file. My regexp is this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)[^>]*?>[\\s]*?</\\1>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(htmlOut);
while (matcher.find())
{
    htmlOut = matcher.replaceAll("");
    matcher = pattern.matcher(htmlOut);
}
```

The problem is it doesn't match any of the empty tags.

FYI: The same regexp `<([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)[^>]*?>[\s]*?</\1>` works in sublime text!

Any approach?

Comment: Obligatory Regex/Html reply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @glenatron: Removing empty tags is well in the realm of what's possible with regex. Even with HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern is OK, but you're using it wrong. `replaceAll()` is called on the string, not on the matcher object.

Also, no need to iterate over the matches - one `replaceAll` is enough:

```
htmlOut = htmlOut.replaceAll("<([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)[^>]*>\\s*</\\1>", "");
```

You don't need lazy quantifiers, though - but that wouldn't affect the match results.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Tim!
Unfortunately this doesn't work either. It simply doesn't find a single empty tag. None. I don't understand why. I already tried just matcher.find()-ing it but this also returns false.

Comment: It works for me - the regex does not allow any whitespace before the tag name and after the closing tag name, though. I don't suppose that's the problem? And you did replace the entire code you posted by my single line, right?

Comment: You mean if I have a tidy'd well indented `<table>` it wouldn't match its empty `<td>`s because of the preceding whitespace? Edit: I tried it with `htmlOut = htmlOut.replaceAll("\\s*<([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)[^>]*>\\s*</\\1>\\s*", "<!--empty-->");` it doesn't work either. Yes I replace my bunch of code with yours ;)

Comment: No, I meant tags like `< a > </ a >` etc., but that doesn't seem to be it.

Comment: Ah alright ;) No. As I said: The same expression works fine in Sublime Text - with the same input HTML. The problem must be in Java itself (do any regexp flags need to be considered?)

Comment: No special flags in use here. What encoding is the string you're matching? Not UTF-16 by any chance?

Comment: Input and Output Encoding of html tidy is set to UTF-8. I'm touching the html right after tidying it.

Comment: Alright, I isolated the problem based on your encoding advise. It seems that there must be some kinda hidden character inbetween. I'll figure that out! Thank you very much!